# Macro that sorts call signs containing letters and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

All the call signs will be in column A and when the macro is run should sort them. The sort is case insensitive usually in all caps. A call sign consists of 1-2 letters(prefix), 1-2 numbers(numbers), then 1-3 letters(suffix) I want to sort each sign by the number, suffix, then prefix in that order.
W9K, BB3C, W9GFO, AB8VN, G3G, A77Bc, KB8HTM, K9DOG, W8AER, K1ZZ, W4BFT, W0CQC, WA6FV, W6TRW, AA5B, W4IY, N4C, K5UZ, K4LRG

Comment: I had to edit out the / and - in the call sign

Comment: examples make no sense to what is written here., sort by number but you have 00 before 0 and you have 99 before 0 in  4 len samples , please provide exact details

Comment: This is similar to a problem I solved with a multi-part string of unique IDs. My suggestion is to locate an empty "work" area of a spreadsheet, then break each callsign apart and store it in three cells of the same row. Next sort that worksheet area in the column order you want -- using the built-in sorting in Excel will be easier than rolling your own. Lastly, take the sorted, 3-column data and re-assemble it into callsign strings and write it back to the original range area.

Comment: The typical customers in my past who've used callsigns in this format are used to seeing them in this single-string format. Certainly reassembling them is optional.

Comment: If the / and - in the call sign separated the prefix numbers and suffix, you should have left them in to easily separate the three parts using a simple formula. Once the sort version is assembled a simple substitute formula can be used to remove them. reply back with a sample of one call sign with the extra characters so we can see if what I am thinking will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will bite. Half the fun of coding is solving a problem for the simple pleasure of knowing you figured it out.

Here is a user defined function (Formula) that you can use to convert the call sign into the format for sorting. Note the numeric portion is zero padded so ones and tens do not sort together before twos and twenties.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FormatCallSign(aCell As Range)
  Dim Nbr As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim tmp As String
  Dim vList As Variant

  For i = 1 To Len(aCell.Value)
    If InStr(1, "1234567890", UCase(Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1))) > 0 Then
      Nbr = Nbr & Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1)
      tmp = tmp & ","
      tmp = Replace(tmp, ",,", ",")
    Else
      If InStr(1, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", UCase(Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1))) > 0 Then
        tmp = tmp & Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1)
      End If
    End If
  Next i
  vList = Split(tmp, ",")



  FormatCallSign = vList(1) & Right("0" & Nbr, 2) & vList(0)
End Function
```

Put the formula in cell B2, for example by using the formulas command on the ribbon and selecting the function from the user defined section.

As asked earlier if the call sign had delimiters in it already, you could use a simple formula to rearrange the parts and exclude the delimiters.

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A3,SEARCH("-",A3)+1,4),RIGHT("0"&MID(A3,SEARCH("/",A3)+1,SEARCH("-",A3)-SEARCH("/",A3)-1),2),LEFT(A3,SEARCH("/",A3)-1))
```

To build a formula like the above, start by constructing it in parts.
First write a Search function to find the "/", then copy it to find the "-"
Then write a mid function to get the characters to the right of the dash, left of the slash, then the numeric section. paste the formulas into a single formula for your masterpiece.

Since it makes better sense to keep the three elements in separate fields for simplified sorting, the above formula can be split into three separate formulas, one for each column.

```
=MID(A3,SEARCH("-",A3)+1,4)
=value(MID(A3,SEARCH("/",A3)+1,SEARCH("-",A3)-SEARCH("/",A3)-1),2))
=LEFT(A3,SEARCH("/",A3)-1)
```

This corrects sorting problems given the three elements are variable length.

Comment: The concatenation puts the three parts in the correct sort sequence. W9K becomes K09W, A77Bc becomes BC77A. Looking at it my error is concatenating and not leaving the three values split into three separate fields. Since the prefix and suffix are not fixed length, it would be better to sort them separately. Split the formula into three separate fields so you can test the sort results and see how variable length strings sort.

Comment: My error. When separated into separate columns there is no need to zero pad the numbers. At most they may need to be wrapped in the Value() function to convert from string to numeric. Once the numeric is populated in a separate column it will sort correctly on its own. Good catch pnuts. I have amended the above.

Answer (score -1):

The initial specification for callsign format is inaccurate, since they can begin with numbers or letters and a logical sort would be by ITU assigned prefix. A function would need a table lookup for country after it determined if the string after the forward slash was a valid country designation.  This is actually a pretty complicated problem.